# Why isn't my header image showing up?

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm using this Sass to style a header on some static pages, but the background image doesn't show up. I'm pretty sure I've got the relative file path right (the stylesheet is in a stylesheets folder and the image is an images folder, both in an assets folder). What else might be causing this?

```
.blue_section_header
    width: 900px
    height: 80px
    font-size: 30px
    font-weight: 700
    padding: 25px 0 0 40px
    color: #fff
    background: #54a0ce url(../images/section_header.png)
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px
    -moz-border-radius: 4px
    border-radius: 4px
```

Comment: Is this your actual CSS?

Comment: Can you show your file structure to. Im curious to see if you are pointing to the correct file structure. it looks like your current one is something like this. css images your going from css to images which looks correct but is images possibly one more level down.

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome:

```
1) Open Developer Tools
2) Click the Resources tab at the top
3) Open the Frames folder
4) Look for the Images folder and open it
```

Do you see your image in the Images folder? If you don't see the image that means that your relative path is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you! That helped me finally figure it out.

Comment: @DeFeNdog I'll upvote you haha

Comment: Heheh thanks Jonathon!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a few things. 
You miss the opening and closing brackets (`{`, `}`).
And the semi-colon behind every line.
It should be :

```
.blue_section_header { 
     width: 900px;
     height: 80px;
     font-size: 30px;
     font-weight: 700;
     padding: 25px 0 0 40px;
     color: #fff;
     background: #54a0ce url(../images/section_header.png);
     -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px;
     border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm using Sass, so no brackets or semi-colons are needed.